# Is it possible to globally solve a general coordinate-wise monotone nonlinear system 3x3?

Tags: numerics, nonlinear-equations

Consider a system
$$
F_i(x, y, z) = 0, \quad i = 1, 2, 3
$$
with $F_i$ monotonic w.r.t. $x, y$ and $z$.

The system 2x2 can be easily solved with [alternating direction method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513660/multivariate-bisection-method/58512466#58512466) that will find all its roots.

The problem is to find all roots of the 3x3 system with monotonic coordinate functions. Is it possible in a general case? In other words, it is necessary to find all intersections of 3 surfaces with positive coordinates of normal vectors in 3D space.

Illustration 1: linear case, 1 root
[image: Fig. 1]

Illustration 2: nonlinear case, 2 roots
[image: Fig. 2]

Comment: I suppose that, unlike 2D problem, it's impossible in a general case. We may check all 2d cross-sections going through a given point $x_0$ but we can't draw a conclusion that a definite orthant of the point $x_0$ does not contain any roots by using only information about intersections of the surfaces in the cross-sections. Though, that might be a simplification.

Comment: But how the information about 2d cross-sections (in xy, yz and xz planes going though $x_0$) should be used to ensure convergence sequentially to all roots - don't definitely know.

Comment: If you give us one or two examples of what you are trying to do, we might be able to help you better

Comment: Your problem sounds a lot like using numerical continuation may be appropriate. It is used to 'walk' along those trajectories of x,y,z where your condition holds. These methods can be generalized to any dimension, but are limited to finding all adjacent coordinates for your condition. If the roots are not connected they may not find them.

Comment: Please also specify what exactly you mean with monotonic.

Comment: Monotonic here has regular definition, f(x,y,z) is monotonically increasing in x, as well as in y and z, where f = F_i, i = 1,2,3. I tried considering 2x2 cross-sections going through a current guess and find intersections of F_i and F_j in those cross-sections. If the root could be characterized with an extremum property, the monotonic convergent method found it, but in this case it is not necessary, I tried to construct a method preserving signs of F_i (like in 2d) but maybe it is needed here to move to neighbour domains of definite signs where the extremum property is fulfilled.

Comment: I would give interval root finding (e.g. https://github.com/JuliaIntervals/IntervalRootFinding.jl) a try. It can find and bound *all* the roots even in the presence of roundoff errors.